# MySQL Select into column on condition multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables in a mysql database:

-questions(id, content)

-answers(id, content, question) where the question is a foreign key that tells us to which question the answer relates

-survey(survey_id, answer) where the survey_id is unique for one person that took the survey and the answer indicates the answer he gave.

Now I would like to write up a query that would show me a table which would contain the Id of the person that took the survey and all the answers he gave in different columns.

This is my query:

```
select survey.survey_id, 
    CASE WHEN answers.question = 1
    then answers.content
    end
    as 'Question 1',
    CASE WHEN answers.question = 2
    then answers.content
    end
    as 'Question 2'
    from survey inner join answers on survey.answer_id = answers.id;
```

But I don't think this is the way to go, I get what is shown on the picture (with the nulls)[image]

Now what I would like to get is here:[image]

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: you have only two answer  for each survey_id??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.survey_id, 
       max(case when a.question = 1 then a.content end) as Question_1,
       max(case when a.question = 2 then a.content end) as Question_2
from survey s inner join
     answers a
     on s.answer_id = a.id
group by s.survey_id;
```

Notes:

- All tables have aliases.
- All columns are *qualified*, meaning that they unambiguously specify the table they come from.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use single quotes for table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a (fake) aggregation function for reduce the rows eg:

```
  select survey.survey_id, 
      max(CASE WHEN answers.question = 1
        then answers.content
      end)  as 'Question 1',
      max(CASE WHEN answers.question = 2
        then answers.content
      end)  as 'Question 2'
  from survey inner join answers on survey.answer_id = answers.id
  group by survey.survey_id
```